# Get Firebase user document without knowing which collection the user is in

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the Firebase project, Firestore is set up so that there are organizations and user documents inside each organization. Therefore grabbing the additional information about users would require me to query the following path: organizations/{user's organization id}/{users}/{user id}. How would I access the user's information by only knowing their id? I'm sure I can query all users from all organizations but that would probably take a long time and breach security rules since the user is querying other users not in their organization.

This is the current code that takes the basic information of the auth user

```
const authStateChanged = async (user) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    if (!user) {
        clear();
        return;
    }
    
    setAuthUser({
        uid: user.uid,
        email: user.email
    });
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

Comment: You must either 1) restructure your data entirely to make users queryable by ID as a top level collection without an organization ID, or 2) restructure your security rules to allow a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) across all users subcollections in all orgs (and there is nothing at all slow about that). For that query to work, you must also store the ID as a field in the user doc.  There is really no alternative without more complex restructuring or making use of custom claims to store an org ID for the user.

Comment: Would it be fine if I just store the ord ID as a custom claim? It seems like that would be the easiest.

Comment: Only you can know if it works fine for you and you're willing to manage it that way.

Comment: @DougStevenson It really sounds like an answer, Doug.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 2 ways to get your query working :

1. Query as follows if you know `organizationId` and `userId` :

```
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const getUserById = async (orgId, userId) => {
  const db = getFirestore();
  const userRef = doc(db, 'organizations', organizationId, 'users', userId);
  const userDoc = await getDoc(userRef);

  if (userDoc.exists()) {
    return userDoc.data();
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

// Usage 
const user = await getUserById('org123', 'user456');
console.log(user);
```

You can save the `organizationId` inside the custom claims but then you will also need to verify the `organizationId` is not getting saved in a not accessible user’s custom claims. I have shown that in the security rule ahead.

2. Query as follows using [**Collection group queries**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) if you only know the `userId`:

```
import { getFirestore, collectionGroup, query, where, getDocs, documentId } from 'firebase/firestore';

const getUsersById = async (userId) => {
  const db = getFirestore();
  const usersRef = collectionGroup(db, 'users');
  // Here userId should be complete document path not just document id
  const q = query(usersRef, where(documentId(), '==', userId));
  // Work Around would be to store userId inside the document then query against it
  const q2 = query(usersRef, where("userId", '==', userId));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

  const users = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    users.push(doc.data());
  });

  return users;
};

// Usage
const users = await getUsersById('user123');
console.log(users);
```

I have used  the `documentId()` method from the [**documentations**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#static-documentid) which is really quite helpful in this scenario.

**Edit** : To use `docuemntId()` with `collectionGroup` we need to compare it against the complete document path. So it is best to store the `userId` inside the user's document and compare it against that.

For any of the above approaches your security rules for the same would look something like follows.

**Note** : I have not tested these rules on a large number of documents; these are merely tested on 2-3 documents.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow any authenticated user to read their own user document for Approach 1
    match /organizations/{orgId}/users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }

    // Allow any authenticated user to read any documents in their own organization
    match /organizations/{orgId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && isUserInOrg(request.auth.uid, orgId);
    }

    // Custom function to check if a user is in an organization
    function isUserInOrg(userId, orgId) {
      return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/organizations/$(orgId)/users/$(userId));
    }

    // Allow a user to read their own user document across all organizations for Approach 2
    match /{document=**}/users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Reference : [**Access other documents**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents%5D) , [**Collection group queries**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query)